# Открытие двух модальных окон fancybox 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Мне нужно открыть модальное окно когда одно уже открыто.

такое возможно?

знаю что так можно в `fancybox 3`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Вот наглядный пример:

```html
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>


<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#foo">Открыть окно</a>

<div style="display: none" id="foo">Окно 1<br><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#foo-2">Открыть окно 2</a></div>
<div style="display: none" id="foo-2">Окно 2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

С fancybox не работал, но модалки можно сделать и без него. Обычно в вебе делается так: открывается модальное окно, когда нужно второе открыть, первое скрывается, а вторая модалка показывается. Вот небольшой пример.

```js
function togglePopup(state,id) {
  toggleModalById(id);
  $('.container-modal')[state ? 'fadeIn': 'fadeOut']();
}

function toggleModalById(id) {
  $('.modal-block').hide();
  $(id).show();
}

$('#btn-for-modal1').click(function () {
       togglePopup(true, '#modal1');
})
$('#btn-for-modal2').click(function () {
       togglePopup(true, '#modal2');
})

$('.container-modal').click(function () {
    togglePopup(false);
 })
```

```css
.container-modal {
   height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
}

.modal-block {
  padding:20px;
  background: #fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:25%;
  display:none;
}

.toggle-btn {
  
  margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-modal">
     <div id="modal1" class="modal-block">
         <div>Первое мождальное окно</div>
     </div>
  
       <div id="modal2" class="modal-block">
         <div>Второе мождальное окно</div>
     </div>
</div>

<button id="btn-for-modal1" class="toggle-btn">toggle modal 1</button>

<button id="btn-for-modal2" class="toggle-btn ">toggle modal 2</button>
```